# How do you get javascript to wait for input before continuing to run

Tags: input, wait, pause

I'm trying to make a little text rpg in javascript.

I have a text field the user types into for input, then presses enter. And the games text changes to reflect their input.

I then need the code to wait for further input before running anymore code. Essentially, how do you pause and wait for further input. And I mean not just once, but for the whole game, every time.  [Here's an image of my code and the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkPjF.png)

```
const gamesText = document.querySelector('.games-text');
const usersInput = document.querySelector('#users-text-input');

StartTheGame();
function StartTheGame() {
    gamesText.innerHTML = "Welcome to the game!~ What is your name?";

    usersInput.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
        if (e.key === "Enter") {
            const usersName = usersInput.value;
            gamesText.innerHTML = "Good luck " + usersName + "!~";
            localStorage.setItem('name', usersName);
        }
    });

}

//EventListeners 
document.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
        gamesText.innerHTML = `This is the only text 
        you'll see, after pressing ENTER once.`;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```js
usersInput.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
        if (e.key === "Enter") {
         if(usersInput.value.length > 3){
            const usersName = usersInput.value;
            gamesText.innerHTML = "Good luck " + usersName + "!~";
            localStorage.setItem('name', usersName);
         }else{
          //message of error
         }
            
        }
    });
```